# Can we just have a place for programmers to ask questions?

Tags: discussion, moderation

i understand in stackoverflow, questions are closed as "off topic" "not constructive"

that is why we come here!! /* programmers */ should be alot more liberal as to the type of questions allowed.

example: [Comparison of IDEs for C++ and C development on Linux: KDevelop, Eclipse, NetBeans, CodeBlocks and Anjuta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/125796/comparison-of-ides-for-c-and-c-development-on-linux-kdevelop-eclipse-netbea?rq=1)

this is a perfect question for programmers. this place is to heavily moded. chill

---

[Dangers of too eager moderation](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2794/dangers-of-too-eager-moderation?rq=1)

even my meta question gets down-voted... no wonder this place is not too popular.

Comment: Why do you believe that that question is a perfect question within the context of the StackExchange Q&A format?

Comment: there needs to be a stackexchange/b thats all im saying.

Comment: Why does it have to be Stack Exchange that does it? There are other sites that are trying to fill that niche and have a framework for such a design.  Between slant.co, ask slashdot, quora to name a few. The focus of the efforts of SE is on the SE Q&A site. To try to design a SE polling / random discussion site would take resources away from what they do (and do well).

Comment: i love stackoverflow, and am always very careful to ask good questions.. i just want to start an "off-topic" discussion with stackoverflow users.. just seems that this is what programmers should be. anyways

Comment: *Discussions* are off topic on all SE sites.  They are ok in chat rooms.  SE was intentionally designed to make discussions difficult - people come here to ask a question and get an answer (thats the entire cross SE design).  Discussions also have lots of back and forth which on a large site has difficulty (I would suggest reading [A Group Is Its Own Worst Enemy](http://www.shirky.com/writings/group_enemy.html) and consider the fourth point on "Things you have to design for" -  this document was certainly part of consideration when designing the SE framework).

Comment: Are you saying that 4chan /b/ is actually a good thing?  Why would we want something like that here?  Nothing good has come from it and nothing good could ever come of it

Comment: Downvotes on meta mean "I disagree" - it's different here.

Comment: It may seem to be "not too popular" to you, but the popularity of this site has grown significantly over the course of the last year or so as we maintain carefully manicured content of high quality. The proof is in the pudding.

Comment: last time i was here, it was a mess. nice cleanup job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This was tried in the initial days of Programmers and it failed spectacularly.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

The site came very close to be being shut down, but we managed, through the herculean efforts of everybody - moderators, community managers and committed users, to turn it around and have a site that is, on the whole, useful.

Comment: I wonder what the graph of programmers looks like.

Comment: @jaybny which graph?  The usage history in the link *is* programmers.SE's history of site activity.

Comment: ok got it......